Import kv module to cloudflare worker with javascript
I am trying to import the kv module to my cloudflare worker (i.e. to do put and get requests to it). I created it with wrangler (v3.78.12). I just dont know how to import it lol
From some research, I have tried
import { KVNameSpace } from '@Cloudflare/kw-namespace'
import { KVNameSpace } from 'cloudflare:kv'
import { KV } from 'cloudflare-workers-kv'

none of these worked
If anyone knows what it is, please let me know, as well as letting me know what to do after that (i.e. how to actually do the get and put requests)
I am very new to backend developing
If you need my code, I can give it to you

The binding to a KV service is defined at env level, in your worker script:
First, define the binding name from your dashboard, or in wrangler.toml
Next, use that binding like so:
await env.BINDING_NAME.get("key")
or, to store new values:
await env.BINDING_NAME.put(key, value)
The setup procedure seems a bit complicated at first, but then it goes faster.
I feel more comfortable doing the settings from the dashboard
Docs here
